# What does the "Unlink" button do in "Queue Jenkins job" in a TFS Build Definition

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a Queue Jenkins job step in my build definition, and inside it I have a Service Endpoint parameter. It has an Unlink button but I'm not sure what it does.

I clicked it but even when unlinked, the service endpoint works correctly.

[image]

What is its purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching, it seems to create a parameter in the root page of the build definition and link it to the parameter inside the step. If I click "Unlink", this parameter disappears from the root page (but is still there inside the jenkins step).

[image]